# Why does my Xcode Simulator only show a blank white screen and app title?

Tags: ios, storyboard

I'm making an application in Xcode, and it's my first time using it so I'm just a little confused. I have my storyboards with a basic set up of how I want it to look, but when I run the simulator it only shows a blank white screen. Any advice? I feel like I am just missing a step somewhere.

[image: Also attached a screenshot of my Xcode setup if that helps at all.]

I've adding segues to the buttons (present modally for all of them based on a tutorial I was following) and created a main view control, as well as a log-in screen. I haven't been able to test any of this because of the simulator being blank.

[Here is a link to the code on Github - most of it is still base code.](https://github.com/rebecca-42/CL-FinalDraft.git)

Comment: Can you post your project publicly on GitHub so we can look at it and see what the problem is?

Comment: What you posted on GitHub is three loose files: two swift files and the storyboard. But loose files don't make a project. You need to upload the _project folder_ to GitHub. This will be a folder containing, for instance, the Xcode project file.

Comment: However, even from what you've posted it's pretty obvious what the issue is. You have started with a SwiftUI project and added a storyboard to it. That's a contradiction. You either want a storyboard-based project, with a storyboard and UIKit swift file (view controller), or you want a SwiftUI project, which would have no storyboard.

Comment: Maybe you've started with a tutorial that is so old that it doesn't even know that SwiftUI is a thing?

Comment: For some reason I'm unable to upload folders onto GitHub, but I think you're right with the issue. When I was choosing templates in the beginning I must have chosen something that's incompatible with what I'm doing. Thank you for the help! I'll edit this post tomorrow with an update after I change it.